# Accessing 9gag API in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am making a simple angular/rails app as a 9gag viewer, just for practice. [I am using the unofficial api](https://github.com/k3min/infinigag) and it seems to work. I set up the rails app, and rails is just serving angular. I can call the api in just a javascript file, and it spits out the data, so I know that part works.

When I go into the console, I see the "success" message I put in, so the only code that isn't working is the angular. Here is what I have so far;

**app.js**

```
window.App = angular.module('chadder', ['ngResource'])
```

**hot_ctrl.js**

```
App.controller('HotCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
  $scope.data = [];
  $http.get('http://infinigag.eu01.aws.af.cm/trending/0').success(function(data){
     console.log("success");
      return $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HotCtrl" id="test">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="hot in hot">
      <h2>{{ data.caption }}</h2>
      <p>{{ data.link }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was using a service that I have used to access other rails api's, but due to the errors I was getting, I think this just lets you access an api that you have locally (i.e. localhost:3000/api/something.json) . I'm not using it, but I did have this set up;

**hot.js**

```
App.factory('Chadder', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://infinigag.eu01.aws.af.cm/trending/0', []);
  }
]);
```

Because I'm seeing the "success", and I can see the API data on a webpage, I'm pretty sure the only thing I'm doing wrong is just not giving the right end points to angular. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reading the source data object properly

It is returned as

```
{
  data: [/* array of objects */],
  paging :{} /*object*/
}
```

In addition your `ng-repeat` makes no sense . You have no scope array `hot` to repeat. Then inside the `ng-repeat` you aren't referencing the object `hot` you create.

Using your current scope set up you need to repeat `data.data`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="hot in data.data">
      <h5>{{ hot.caption }}</h5>
      <p>{{ hot.link }}</p>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EWCpRbbGImjk5ynydIeI?p=preview)**</kbd>